# Deserilization issue on spark-submit for scala class

Tags: java, scala, spark-submit

I am trying to work on a scala and java combined project, I have a scala class which abbreviated  structure is as follows

```
 case class Dl(name:String, length:Int) extends Serializable 

 class DlStruct private(xs:List[Dl]) extends Serializable {
    def this()= this(Nil)

    private def +=(dl:DataLayout): RowSchema =
      new RowSchema(xs :+ dl)

    def appendDl(fieldName:String, fieldLength:Int):DlStruct=
      this += Dl(fieldName,fieldLength)

 }
```

The above class is called from a java object to populate the DlStruct and after its completion, I am writing the class file out as serialized file.

When I again deserialize the file and convert it back to object, it is working perfectly fine when I am working from IntelliJ but if I try to run the same code from spark-submit it is throwing following error:-

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field somepackage.DlStruct.xs of type scala.collection.immutable.List in instance of somepackage.DlStruct.xs
at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2205)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.checkObjectFieldValueTypes(ObjectStreamClass.java:2168)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkObjFieldValueTypes(ObjectStreamClass.java:1422)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultCheckFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:2450)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2357)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2166)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1668)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2434)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2328)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2166)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1668)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:482)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:440)
```

There also isn't an issue for deserialization of common java object

The code snippet for deserialization

```
 File file = new File(serializedFilePath);
 FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
 ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fin);

 infoHolder = (ObjectCarrier) in.readObject(); // <- this line gives error if it has scala object, else runs smoothly

 in.close();
 fileIn.close();
```

Spark version- 2.4.4
Scala Version- 2.12.8
Java- 1.8

Comment: Which spark and scala versions are you using? And are they the same versions that `spark-submit` uses? And by the way, case classes are serializable by default.

Comment: The version specified in my POM is 
<scala.version>2.12.8</scala.version>
        
     <spark.version>2.4.4</spark.version>

Comment: And which JDK version? It looks fairly recent based on that stacktrace. Not all recent JDK versions are guaranteed to work with all not-so-recent scala versions https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html

Comment: its openjdk 1.8.0_242

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the JVM that gave you that stacktrace should be more recent than 1.8 though.

Comment: I am running the final jar as follows spark-submit myprj.jar, i've done nothing else, do I need to do something else

Comment: @Jasper-M so my spark-shell locally is 3.0.0 but the code is written using 2.4.4, however even if I create a jar using 3.0.0 instead of 2.4.4 spark version i am still getting the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I had to convert the scala class to java to have it finally start working in spark-submit, I hope someone finds a better answer for this.